# Запуск Activity с параметрами

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

Есть 2 Activity. В первом 4 ImageButton, во втором 1 TextView. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на ImageButton открывалось второе Activity и устанавливался нужный текст (соответствующий нажатой кнопке).

Main Activity

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.ib_common:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScrollingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("common",1);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.ib_woman:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScrollingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("woman",2);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.ib_man:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScrollingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("man",3);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.ib_work:
            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScrollingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("work",4);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }

}
```

Second Activity

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getIntExtra("common",1) == 1){
        mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.common_rules));
     }
    if (intent.getIntExtra("woman",2) == 2){
        mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.woman_rules));
     }
    if (intent.getIntExtra("man",3) == 3){
        mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.man_rules));
     }
    if (intent.getIntExtra("work",4) == 4){
        mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.work));
     }
```

С таким кодом в TextView всегда устанавливается один и тот же текст ("work"). Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вот почему

```
if (intent.getIntExtra("work",4) == 4){
    mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.work));
 }
```

если даже нету `work` в Extra, вы даете параметр по умолчанию 4. и получается 4 == 4

нужно так

```
if (intent.getIntExtra("work",0) == 4){
    mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.work));
 }
```

---

или для всех

```
if (intent.getIntExtra("common", 0) == 1){
    mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.common_rules));
}
if (intent.getIntExtra("woman", 0) == 2){
    mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.woman_rules));
}
if (intent.getIntExtra("man", 0) == 3){
    mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.man_rules));
}
if (intent.getIntExtra("work", 0) == 4){
    mText.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.work));
}
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо !