# Запуск Activity с распознаванием параметров adapterView

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent, imageview

Пишу первое приложение. На одном из этапов возникла задачка: есть две последовательные Activity, которые надо связать. В первой- Grid View, к которой подключен ImageAdaper:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

//Добавляем изображения в массив:
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.1,R.drawable.2,
        R.drawable.3,R.drawable.4,
        R.drawable.5,R.drawable.6,
};

//Конструктор:
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 300));
    return imageView;
}
```

Сама Activity получает из адаптера инфу, и выводит в GridView 6 картинок-image view:

```
public class Pick_type extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_type);

    GridView Grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.activity_pick_type);

    Grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); }
```

На этом этапе все замечательно.

Далее задача при клике на соответствующую картинку-одну из 6 imageview, открывать в новой activity2  imageview всего один, но строго заданный (например, вьюха R.drawable.1  в первой activity- соответствует вьюхе R.drawable.11 во второй activity, R.drawable.2 - соотв. R.drawable.22 и т.д.).

В поисках возможных вариантов нашел вот-такой ответ: 
[запуск activity с параметрами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477837).

При попытках сделать подобное застопорился. Сделал во второй activity вьюшку и intent-преемник. Но вот соединить их с первой activity не выходит.

Вторая activity

```
    ImageView imagetake = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getIntExtra("image1",1) == 1){
        imagetake.setImageResource(R.drawable.11);
```

1) Переменная mThumbIds - не может быть применена к статическому контенту, по мнению android studio. Соотвественно, конструкция как в примере

```
                public void onClick(ImageAdapter(this)) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (ImageAdapter.mThumbIds.getId()) {

                    case R.drawable.top:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,activity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image1", 1);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
```

у меня не работает.

2) В приведенном вопросе, элементы есть в .xml и им присвоен метод onClick и id. Как присвоить это моим вьюхам, понять пока не могу (и вообще, может есть другой путь).

Подскажите, кто сможет, какие есть варианты чтобы выполнить мою задачу, или помогите разобраться в ошибках.

Comment: В чем проявляется неработоспособность? Метод `onClick(...)` Вызывается? Где он расположен?

Comment: Немного разобрался, переделал на примере "GridView с картинками"[ссылка](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/gridview.php), OnClick работает, выводит в activity2 ту же самую картинку, что и в  activity1, в виде:                                                                                  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);          Но не понимаю как мне теперь одну картинку на выходе, привязать к другой в drawable ? В каком месте это делать, то установки ресурса или после?.